# single pixel manipulation with php GD

Tags: php, image-processing, php-gd

First I'm referring to a previous question [Change image per pixel and save to db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146323/change-image-per-pixel-and-save-to-db)

I found that the html5 canvas isn't suitable because it's hard to keep the source-image secret. That's why I'm trying to achieve my goal with the PHP GD library. I never worked with this library so I have some difficulties. I guess I need the following functions

- imagecreatetruecolor for creating the image in the browser
- imagecolorallocate for returning rgb from source-image
- imagesetpixel for drawing the random pixels

  ```
  $x = 200; //width of image
  $y = 200; //height of image

  $gd = imagecreatetruecolor ($x, $y);
   $color = imagecolorallocate($gd, $r, $g, $b) //not sure how to retrieve the rgb from the source image

  Then I need a function for drawing random pixels with imagesetpixel.
  imagesetpixel($gd, $posx,$posy, $color); // not sure how to retrieve the x and y position of each pixel.
  ```

I'm not a star with PHP, that's why my search is stuck with these GD functions. Hope you can give me a start-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the "features" of the random function is that it's pseudorandom, i.e., it will always output the same sequence given the same seed.

So you could store, for each "image":

```
sourcefile   - the name of the source image
seed         - integer, maybe the start time of this sequence
position     - number of pixels that need to be shown, or maybe % completion
```

So say that you want to output the image `$sourcefile` with seed `$seed` and `$position` percentage of pixels visible. You don't even need to use alpha:

```
// Load image
$src = imageCreateFromPNG($sourcefile); // Assume image is PNG

// Create work image
$new = imageCreateTrueColor(ImageSX($src), ImageSY($src)); // new image of same size

mt_srand($seed); // Seed the Mersenne Twister generator

// Number of pixels to set: $position = 0: NONE, $position = 100: ALL
$pixels = round($position*imageSX($src)*imageSY($src)/100);

// Now we have a problem: if we do $pixels attempts, mt_rand might sometimes
// return the same pixel again. So we end up setting less than $pixels pixels.

// So we do this the expensive way, saving an array of yet-to-be-used pixels.
$max     = ImageSX($src)*ImageSY($src);
$pixelid = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    $pixelid[] = $i;

$W  = ImageSX($src);

while($pixels--)
{
    // Extract one pixel
    $chosen = $pixelid[$idx = mt_rand(0, $pixels)];

    array_splice ($pixelid, $idx, 1); // Remove extracted pixel from array

    $x = $chosen % $W;
    $y = ($chosen - $x)/ $W;

    $rgb = imagecolorat($src, $x, $y);
    $pix = imagecolorsforindex($src, $rgb);
    $rgb = imageColorAllocate($new, $pix['red'], $pix['green'], $pix['blue']);
    imageSetPixel($new, $x, $y, $rgb);
}

ImageDestroy($src);

// $new has now exactly $pixels set to the same pixels of $src,
// the rest are undefined (you can fill $new with white beforehand...)
Header("Content-Type: image/png");
ImagePNG($new);
```

## Variations

Instead of splicing the array, you could blot out the "used" pixels, even if this does not give a uniform distribution:

```
$cnt = count($pixelid);

while($pixels--)
{
    // Extract one pixel
    $idx = mt_rand(0, $cnt);
    // If the extracted pixel is null, find next pixel that is unextracted
    // and if there are none, restart from the beginning of the array.
    while (-1 == ($chosen = $pixelid[$idx]))
        if ($cnt == ++$idx)
            $idx = 0;
    $chosen = $pixelid[$idx];
    $pixelid[$idx] = -1;
```

Or you could just... retry. But this can be expensive when the image is almost complete.

```
$cnt = count($pixelid);
while($pixels--)
{
    // Extract one pixel
    for ($idx = mt_rand(0, $cnt); $pixelid[$idx] != -1; $idx = mt_rand(0, $cnt))
        ;
    $chosen = $pixelid[$idx];
    $pixelid[$idx] = -1;
```

If you do not care that the image is rebuilt always in different manners, you can use `array_shuffle()` instead of `mt_rand()`, and at each iteration i extract the i-th pixel from `$pixelid`.

A last option is to reimplement the `array_shuffle()` using `mt_rand` as detailed in the manual page (see example by tim at leethost dot com):

```
function array_new_shuffle(&$items, $seed)
{
    mt_srand($seed);
    for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        $j = @mt_rand(0, $i);
        list($items[$i], $items[$j]) = array($items[$j], $items[$i]);
    }
}
```

So you would call `array_new_shuffle()` against `$pixelid` using `$seed`, and then extract the elements from the shuffled array in sequence:

```
for ($idx = 0; $idx < $pixels; $idx++)
{
    $chosen = $pixelid[$idx];
    ...
```

## Large Images

For large images, handling the array is too expensive and you get out of memory. So, to avoid `mt_rand()` repeatedly hitting the same pixels (which can get really problematic when image is 99% complete, and therefore the probability of hitting at random one of the still viable 1% pixels is, of course, 1%), this hack uses another image as the index.

This limits the "array" to 2^24 entries, that is, an image with a side of 2^12, or 4096 pixels.

The memory savings are huge: each image pixel costs now 16 bytes, instead of around 176 (this on my Linux 64bit machine). This means that a 1024x1024 pixel image requires only about 17M of RAM.

On my system, this script processes around 180k pixels per second (a 1024x1024 image was 100% processed in 7.4 seconds, of which around 2 were needed for image loading and setup).

```
$seed = 0;
$position = 2;
$sourcefile = '/home/lserni/Lena19721024-filtered.png';

mt_srand($seed); // Seed the Mersenne Twister generator

// Load image
    $src = ImageCreateTrueColor(512,512);
// $src = imageCreateFromPNG($sourcefile); // Assume image is PNG
$W  = ImageSX($src);
$H  = ImageSY($src);

// Total number of pixels
$size   = $W*$H;

if (($W > 4095) || ($H > 4095))
   die("Image too big");

// Create work image
$new = imageCreateTrueColor($W, $H); // new image of same size

/*
if ($position > 50)
{
    $position = 100-$position;
    $tmp = $src;
    $src = $new;
    $new = $tmp;
}
*/

// Number of pixels to set: $position = 0: NONE, $position = 100: ALL
$pixels = round($position*$size/100.0);

// Create a temporary buffer image of the same size
$fix = imageCreateTrueColor($W, $H);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    $b = $i & 0xFF;
    $g = ($i >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $r = ($i >> 16) & 0xFF;
    imageSetPixel($fix, $i % $W, floor($i / $W), imageColorAllocate($fix, $r, $g, $b));
}

while($pixels--)
{
    // Recover one of the available pixel indexes
    $idx = mt_rand(0, $size--);

    // Recover index from image
    $y   = floor($idx / $W);
    $x   = $idx % $W;
    $idx = imageColorAt($fix, $x, $y);
    $lst = imageColorAt($fix, $size % $W, floor($size / $W));
    $b   = $lst & 0xff; $lst >>= 8;
    $g   = $lst & 0xff; $lst >>= 8;
    $r   = $lst & 0xff;
    imageSetPixel($fix, $x, $y, imageColorAllocate($fix, $r, $g, $b));

    // Whew. Now recover true x and y from new $idx
    $y   = floor($idx / $W);
    $x   = $idx % $W;

    $rgb = imagecolorat($src, $x, $y);
    $pix = imagecolorsforindex($src, $rgb);
    $rgb = imageColorAllocate($new, $pix['red'], $pix['green'], $pix['blue']);
    imageSetPixel($new, $x, $y, $rgb);
}
ImageDestroy($src);

// $new has now exactly $pixels set to the same pixels of $src,
// the rest are undefined (you can fill $new with white beforehand...)
// die("Memory: " . memory_get_peak_usage());
Header("Content-Type: image/png");
ImagePNG($new);
```

## Optimization

You'll notice a commented section in the above code. If it so happens that `$position` is more than 50%, say, 70%, it doesn't makes sense to create an empty image and copy 70% of pixels from the good image to the empty image. It makes more sense to copy 30% of empty pixels from the empty image to the good image, "blacking" it out. This can be accomplished by simply swapping `$new` and `$src` and adjusting `$position`. I haven't really thoroughly tested this code; that's why I left it commented. But you're welcome to give it a try.

## Implementation

The advantage in using the PRNG is that **you don't need to save any image**, but only `seed` and `position` - typically eight bytes in all.

If person A receives position 1, and asks to receive positions up to 5 (i.e. 5% of image visible), and you save the seed and this value of 5, and use it for person B, then person B will see the same 5% that person A got.

All without any images being saved or loaded except the original one.

If you can pass seed and position in the $_GET parameters, you can show in the browser the image at different stages (e.g. `image.php?seed=12345678&position=5` would show the image with 5% of pixels set. You can also specify the number of pixels instead of their percentage, of course).

This works *as long as the pixels are chosen at random*: if person A gets to **choose** the exact pixels he or she wants, then **this approach is not valid** and you need to save the individual pixel positions, which can be done in several ways: using a flatfile holding couples of (x,y) in binary format, or saving the whole image. The latter approach is easier to understand and needs storage for one whole image at each step, so if this is a game and you want to "replay" it, you might need huge disk space. The first approach might reasonably require six bytes per pixel, i.e. equivalent to an image which has the same height and is twice as wide as the original, or as few as four bytes per pixel.

Comment: Wow.. see, this kind of scripting is right now out of my league. But I see your point, so I'm tested out your script (part before variations). And unfortunately I get this error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)

Comment: Hm. The memory error makes me think that you're handling a VERY big image. I'll add an alternative. The other error was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: well.. the image I was handling was 300x300. Not that big I think.

Comment: Hm. Actually, while I get a peak memory usage for the array of 170M for a 1024x1024 image, a 300x300 ought to have costed (i.e. I checked now what it costs on my system) around 20M. That's where I got the 170 byte figure from: (170-20)M/(1024^2-300^2). Yet you had allocated around 128M. You can post the whole script in another question if you like: in addition to the pixel choice, there must be another problem in there somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I'v tested it with a $sourcefile, but it doesn't do what I aspect it to do. I Don't see in the script where the file is saved? The script has to save the file to $sourcefile, so the next time it opens the image, it will show the same visible pixels that where set in previous runs.

When person A adds 7 visible pixels to the image, person B will see the image with the same 7 visible pixels. When person B adds 4 pixels, they both should see the same 11 visible pixels.

Comment: I did some testing with saving the file: ImagePNG($new, './source.png'); But then I get the error "De image can not be displayed, because it contains errors"

Comment: To investigate these errors, remove the `Header` call or change MIME type from Image/PNG to `text/plain`. But this error is probably because you save the PNG to a file, don't also output it to the browser, and so the browser is expecting a PNG and doesn't get it, and complains. Two calls to ImagePNG - the new, then the old - ought to fix that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20238/discussion-between-lserni-and-user1786301)

Answer (score 0):

replace RANDOM_COLOR with your random color value

this will replace all the pixels ,

```
for($i=0;$i < $x;$i++) {
    for($e = 0;$e < $y;$e++) {
        imagesetpixel($gd, $i,$e, $RANDOM_COLOR);
    }
}
```

if you want to set only a few random pixels , make sure you set them in a 0 and width -1, 0 and height -1 range

for example

```
$i = rand(0,$width-1);
$e = rand(0,$height - 1);
imagesetpixel($gd, $i,$e, $RANDOM_COLOR);
```

you could use it in a loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply ogres. But the colors don't have to be random. Each pixelvalue (rgb and x,y) of the output, needs to be the same as the source-image. Only thing is that the imagesetpixel doesn't draw the whole image in one step but a random number of pixels at random positions in each step (by step I mean the amount of pixels someone chooses from a form). After each step the picture needs to be saved to the db so the next time the same amount of pixels will be visible. The amount of pixels will increase so the image in the browser will resemble the source-image.

Comment: you could use imagecopy for copying a part of the image in another image , so you will show this copied image to user , then save showed x/y , after form submit you will increase x and y ... finally user will get full image

create new fixed size image , copy part of the image in the new created resource , then display it , everytime form submits you must increaze the size of copying 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ogres I got it partially working.

What I do is manipulating a toplayer and after the manipulation, merge it with function imagecopy with the source-image. The output is a jpg image.

The manipulation of the toplayer is done with this code

```
for ($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); $y++) {
for ($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); $x++) {
$img = imagecreatefrompng("thecover.png");
    imagealphablending($img, false); // Turn off blending
    $white_color_transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 127);

            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $pixel_color = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);
            if ($pixel_color['red'] == 255 && $pixel_color['green'] == 255 && $pixel_color['blue'] == 255){
                for ($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {
                    imagesetpixel($img, rand(0,300), rand(0,300), $white_color_transparent);
                    }
            }
}
}
```

The color of the toplayer is white, RGB (0,0,0). The script checks for that color and sets, at this point, 200 random pixels to transparent.

It's setting a lot of pixels to transparent, but not the given 200.

Someone who can help me out.